# Magento 1.9 Custom Menu Extension Use in django

Tags: php, python-2.7, magento-1.9

I am trying to use the Magento Custom Menu extension in a django project.
I have modified the menucontent.phtml, but yet my menu items are not reflecting the appropriate captions.

Does anyone know how does the extension work to generate the menu?

Comment: Django is python and Magento is based on PHP. What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to use the magento menu(extension) in a django project. I figured it just about copying the javascript files and then generating the menu data with python instead of PHP. which I have done but for some reason the menu labels are not changing. they still reflect the old PHP ones even inside the Django project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Great. I found the issue. I had not noticed another javascript line at the end of my html file's  tag. so I am home and dry.  Cheers.